# move_uploaded_file not working on update PHP

Tags: php, forms

I am having problems with move_uploaded_file on update. 
all the rows get updated except the row "p_photo" due to an error (not_shown)
error_reporting returns none. any helps? Thanks for your time.

I have the following code:

```
<?php 
session_start();
include("../THISBD/thisbd.php");
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
$logged_user = $_SESSION['this_user'];
$edit_session = $_SESSION['to_edit_p'];
$to_publish = 0;
$ruta = 0;
$p_photo = $_POST['p_photo_dialog_edit']);
$p_photo_name = $_FILES['p_photo_dialog_edit']['name']);
$p_photo_type = $_FILES['p_photo_dialog_edit']['type']);
$p_photo_temp = $_FILES['p_photo_dialog_edit']['tmp_name']);
var_dump($_FILES['p_photo_dialog_edit']['name']);
var_dump($_FILES['p_photo_dialog_edit']['type']);
var_dump($_FILES['p_photo_dialog_edit']['tmp_name']);
$publicacion = addslashes(htmlentities($_POST['to_publish']));
//Finds hastags
preg_match_all('/(#\w+)/', $publicacion, $matches);
foreach ($matches[0] as $hashtag){
    $hashtags.=$hashtag;

}
$text_with_hashtags = preg_replace('/(#(\w+))/', '<a href="../search/?q=/\2">\1</a>', $publicacion);

$select_data_from_the_id = $all_conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM publicaciones WHERE id_comentario = :idcom");
$select_data_from_the_id->bindParam(":idcom", $edit_session);
$select_data_from_the_id->execute();
$fetch_selected_data = $select_data_from_the_id->fetch();
$got_from_user_p = $fetch_selected_data['from_user_p'];
$got_to_user_p = $fetch_selected_data['user'];
$got_foto = $fetch_selected_data['foto'];
$got_nombre = $fetch_selected_data['nombre'];
$got_text_to_edit = $to_publish;
$got_date = 'Enviado el: '.date('d').'/'.date('m').'/'.date('y').' a la(s): '.date('H').':'.date('i').':'.date('s');
$got_time = time();
$got_p_photo = $fetch_selected_data['p_photo'];

//Dock Photo
$dl_id1 = mt_rand(0, 9999999);
$dl_id2 = mt_rand(0, 9999999);
$dl_id3 = mt_rand(0, 9999999);
$dl_id4 = mt_rand(0, 9999999);
$dl_id5 = mt_rand(0, 9999999);
$dl_id6 = mt_rand(0, 9999999);
$dl_id7 = mt_rand(0, 9999999);
$dl_id8 = mt_rand(0, 9999999);
$dl_id9 = mt_rand(0, 9999999);
$dl_id10 = mt_rand(0, 9999999);
$dl_id11 = mt_rand(0, 9999999);
$delete_id = $dl_id1.$dl_id2.$dl_id3.$dl_id4.$dl_id5.$dl_id6.$dl_id7.$dl_id8.$dl_id9.$dl_id10.$dl_id11;
$n_status = 1;
$same_profile = 1;
$id1 = mt_rand(0, 9999999);
$id2 = mt_rand(0, 9999999);
$id3 = mt_rand(0, 9999999);
$id4 = mt_rand(0, 9999999);
$id5 = mt_rand(0, 9999999);
$id6 = mt_rand(0, 9999999);
$id7 = mt_rand(0, 9999999);
$id8 = mt_rand(0, 9999999);
$id9 = mt_rand(0, 9999999);
$id10 = mt_rand(0, 9999999);
$id11 = mt_rand(0, 9999999);

//Dck Photo conditionals
if ($p_photo_type === "image/jpeg"){$p_photo_type = ".jpg";
 move_uploaded_file($p_photo_temp, "../media/".$id1.$id2.$id3.$id4.$id5.$id6.$id7.$id8.$id9.$id10.$id11.$p_photo_type);
$ruta = "../media/".$id1.$id2.$id3.$id4.$id5.$id6.$id7.$id8.$id9.$id10.$id11.$p_photo_type;}
if ($p_photo_type === "image/png"){$p_photo_type = ".png";
 move_uploaded_file($p_photo_temp, "../media/".$id1.$id2.$id3.$id4.$id5.$id6.$id7.$id8.$id9.$id10.$id11.$p_photo_type);
$ruta = "../media/".$id1.$id2.$id3.$id4.$id5.$id6.$id7.$id8.$id9.$id10.$id11.$p_photo_type;}

if(strlen($publicacion) < 1 && strlen($ruta) < 1){return false;}
if((strlen($ruta) < 1) && $logged_user == $got_to_user_p){$n_status = 2; $same_profile = 2;}
if((strlen($ruta) > 1) && $logged_user == $got_to_user_p){$n_status = 2; $same_profile = 2;}
if(strlen($ruta) < 1){$ruta = $got_p_photo; $valid_photo = 1; $n_photo = "nophoto";}
if(strlen($ruta) >= 1){$valid_photo = 2; $n_photo = $ruta;}


$update_rows = $all_conn->prepare("UPDATE publicaciones SET from_user_p = ?, user = ?, foto = ?, nombre = ?, comentario = ?, `time` = ?, `date` = ?, p_photo = ?, to_delete = ?, same_profile = ?, valid_photo = ? WHERE id_comentario = ?");
$update_rows->bindParam("1", $got_from_user_p);
$update_rows->bindParam("2", $got_to_user_p);
$update_rows->bindParam("3", $got_foto);
$update_rows->bindParam("4", $got_nombre);
$update_rows->bindParam("5", $publicacion);
$update_rows->bindParam("6", $got_time);
$update_rows->bindParam("7", $got_date);
$update_rows->bindParam("8", $ruta);
$update_rows->bindParam("9", $delete_id);
$update_rows->bindParam("10", $same_profile);
$update_rows->bindParam("11", $valid_photo);
$update_rows->bindParam("12", $edit_session);
$update_rows->execute();


$delete_row_edit_p_photo_q = $all_conn->prepare("DELETE FROM edit_p_photo WHERE edit_from = :editfrom");
$delete_row_edit_p_photo_q->bindParam(":editfrom", $logged_user);
$delete_row_edit_p_photo_q->execute();

$insert_new_row_edit_p_photo = $all_conn->prepare("INSERT INTO edit_p_photo (edit_p_from, edit_p_photo_url) VALUES (?, ?)");
$insert_new_row_edit_p_photo->bindParam("1", $logged_user);
$insert_new_row_edit_p_photo->bindParam("2", $ruta);
$insert_new_row_edit_p_photo->execute();

?>
```

Comment: `isset` returns true of false, so `$p_photo_temp` is true or false, not `tmp_name` which is what is being expected. The same goes for your `name` and `type` variables.

Comment: I fixed that but there's still the same problem

Comment: Please add your updated code to the question.

Comment: @JonStirling done.

Comment: Can you show the output of `var_dump($_FILES);`? (Also, your new pasted code isn't valid PHP).

Comment: @JonStirling it outputs nothing. I also tried changing folder permissions from 0755 to 0777 (GoDaddy).

Comment: Are you actually just getting a white screen? Make sure error reporting is on and check your error logs. As I said, the code you've provided isn't valid PHP.

Comment: @JonStirling Yes a white screen. why is it invalid? what I need to fix? I'm not a PHP master.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enter enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form. If so please provide $_FILES value.

Comment: it has it. I forgot to mention the form is added via dynamically, does it affect the form?

Comment: Please provide your updated code, including form creation.